# mixing 'left' and 'right' in keyframe (CSS) fails

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

I have a horizontal text-in-several-divs content animation whose width varies depending on user input.  (note: not using jquery so I did not tag that with this question).  There is one div with a text string -- that's one 'unit'.  The user can enter an arbitary number of text strings and we tack a new div onto the right end of the existing text divs:

```
 <div> TEXT1 </div>, <div> TEXT2 </div>, ...., <div> TEXT-N </div>
```

I'm using the keyframe animation technique.  Here's what I need:

1) when the animation starts (0%), the position of the text/divs content of arbitrary length -- I need the left edge of that content to be 2 pixels from the left of the page.

2) when the animation ends (100%), I need the **right** side of the arbitrarily-long text/div content to be about 20 pixels from the right of the page.

So I tried this:

```
 <style> 
  .cssHorizontalAnimatedText
  {
    position:absolute;
    animation:leftMovingTextStuff 10s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  @keyframes leftMovingTextStuff
  {
    0%{ 
        left:20px;
      }
    100%
      {
        right:-20px;
      }
  }
 </style>

 <div class="cssHorizontalAnimatedText" 
         style='width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;height:41px;'>
     <?php echo $theArbitrarilyLongDivsAndText ?>
 </div>
```

I found that if I only use 'right' or only use 'left' in the **keyframes** above, the text-and-divs content will scroll left to right.

But I cannot get my desired positioning (at least it doesn't seem that I can) using *left* values (pixels or %, doesn't seem to matter) only, or using *right* values only.

If I use both *left* and *right* in the **keyframes** above, the arbitrarily-long content doesn't move anymore, it is fixed in position, as if the keyframes refuses to allow mixing *left* and *right* qualifiers in its syntax and still allow the animation to proceed.    But I've seen nothing that states this.

How can I get my arbitrarily-long text-and-divs content set up so that:

1) when the animation starts (0%), the position of the text/divs content of arbitrary length -- the left edge of that content should be 2 pixels from the left of the page.

2) when the animation ends (100%), the **right** side of the arbitrarily-long text/div content needs to be about 20 pixels from the right of the page.

Is there a way to do this with the keyframe?

Comment: I recommend that you create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) to simulate your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to abandon use of keyframes animation for this, unfortunately, and I rolled-my-own using Javascript.

Comment: The question was in fact not found an answer to -- the solution was to abandon the above technique that I was attempting.  The fact that no one offered a solution for deploying keyframe animation here is not the final point -- or maybe it is?  The answer then to my post is "don't attempt keyframe animation for this marquee-type of situation" and it's important that others see the outcome -- which again is that keyframe animation was an inappropriate choice on my part to begin with, to others, save yourself some grief.